# Cerebro.run() on backtrader doesn't output anything?

Tags: python, backtrader

I am trying to run an example strategy on Backtrader however, I am not receiving an error code but simply no output except
[<**main**.SmaCross at 0x12543a880>]

[image]

Can anybody help me please? Thanks a lot.

The code:

```
import backtrader as bt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("VAR1.DE_5Y.csv")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(df['Date'])
df = df.drop(columns=['Date'])

class SmaCross(bt.SignalStrategy):
    def __init__(self):
        sma = bt.ind.SMA(period=50)
        price = self.data
        crossover = bt.ind.CrossOver(price, sma)
        self.signal_add(bt.SIGNAL_LONG, crossover)
        
cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
cerebro.addstrategy(SmaCross)

data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname="VAR1.DE_5Y.csv", nullvalue=0.0, dtformat=('%Y-%m-%d'))

cerebro.adddata(data)

cerebro.run()
```

I didn't use YahooFinanceData and yfinance as the server seems unstable lately and not running on python. So i tried to do the traditional read_csv(file) as a way to feed the data to bt, i'm not sure if this is why it's not outputting anything

Answer (score 0):

`cerebro.run()` should not output anything by default. To show graph try to use `cerebro.plot()` after `cerebro.run()` and you should see graph.

Or you can add analyzers https://www.backtrader.com/docu/analyzers/analyzers/#a-quick-example